# Third-level Menu Item Boostrap MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a menu item which is as follows. I am trying trying to bind these items in my razor view. I got my second level menu item correctly but how do i get the third level menu item.

```
public IEnumerable<Navbar> adminMenuItems()
    {
        var menu = new List<Navbar>();
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 1, nameOption = "Dashboard", controller = "Home", action = "DashBoard", imageClass = "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 0 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 2, nameOption = "Maintenance", controller = "MaintenancePlan", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-wrench fa-fw", status = true, isParent = true, parentId = 0 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 3, nameOption = "Schedules", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 2 });

        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 4, nameOption = "Work Orders", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = true, parentId = 2 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 5, nameOption = "Assigned", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 4 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 6, nameOption = "Company", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 4 });

        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 7, nameOption = "Calender", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 2 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 8, nameOption = "Quotations", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 2 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 9, nameOption = "Assets", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 2 });
        menu.Add(new Navbar { Id = 10, nameOption = "Site", controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-briefcase fa-fw", status = true, isParent = false, parentId = 2 });

        return menu.ToList();
    }
```

"Work Order" is a menu item which is under "Maintenance". "Assigned" and "Company" are the menu items  "Work Order".

Following code will bind my second level menu items. How do i do it for 3rd level menu items. ?.. Please help me .. Thank you..

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.isParent == false && item.parentId == 0)
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action(item.action, item.controller)"><i class="@item.imageClass"></i> @item.nameOption</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.isParent == true)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="@item.imageClass"></i> @item.nameOption<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>                          
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                @foreach (var child in Model.Where(p => p.parentId == item.Id))
                                {
                                    if (child.controller == null)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="#">@child.nameOption</a></li>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action(child.action, child.controller)">@child.nameOption</a></li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>                                
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there will be many ways we can do it. I followed the following method.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.isParent == false && item.parentId == 0)
                {
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action(item.action, item.controller)"><i class="@item.imageClass"></i> @item.nameOption</a></li>
                }                    
                else
                {
                    if (item.isParent == true && item.parentId == 0)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="@item.imageClass"></i> @item.nameOption<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>                          
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                @foreach (var child in Model.Where(p => p.parentId == item.Id))
                                {
                                    if (child.controller == null)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="#">@child.nameOption</a></li>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (child.isParent == true)
                                        {
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="@Url.Action(child.action, child.controller)"><i class="@child.imageClass"></i> @child.nameOption<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                                    @foreach (var childInside in Model.Where(p => p.parentId == child.Id))
                                                    {
                                                        if (childInside.controller == null)
                                                        {
                                                            <li><a href="#">@childInside.nameOption</a></li>
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action(child.action, child.controller)">@childInside.nameOption</a></li>
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action(child.action, child.controller)">@child.nameOption</a></li>
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>                                                                                            
                        </li>
                    }              
                }
            }
```

And I am keeping collection same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper function that you can call recursively.

you need to change your navbar class so it contains a list of navbars

```
public class NavBar 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Children
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<NavBar> Children { get; set; }

    .....
}
```

then create your menu like this

```
        menu.Add(new Navbar
                 {
                     Id = 2, nameOption = "Maintenance", controller = "MaintenancePlan", action = "Index", imageClass = "fa fa-wrench fa-fw", status = true, isParent = true, parentId = 0,
                     childeren = new Collection<Navbar>
                                     {
                                         new Navbar{..., Children = new Collection<NavBar>
                                                                        {
                                                                            ...
                                                                        }},
                                         new Navbar{...}
                                     }
                 });
```

and in your razer view somthing like this.

```
@{

foreach (var item in Model)
{
    createMenuItem(item);
}


}

@helper createMenuItem(Navbar item)
{
if (item.Children.Any())
{
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
        createMenuItem(child);
    }
}
<li>...</li>

}
```

Comment: public virtual ICollection<NavBar> Children { get; set; } is giving error says - Type or namespace 'Navbar' missing.. Do i need to generate the new class again. One as Navbars and other as NavBar ?.

Comment: typo, change ICollection<NavBar> to ICollection<Navbar> and it should be ok